# How to access data inside double nested array in async function - javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I've got array which has another array which contains data i need.

How do i access "0x88def628c16651eb0d86be5ead3d738d0cb27fe947bb786c23105ac5d67a1bd0" in javascript for example? This is being displayed by calling var transakcije.

I've tried with:

transakcije[0][0] but that is not the name of sub array,

transakcije[0],

for loop (transakcija as transakcije) to no avail.

I've searched familiar answers but found none to my aid. I appreciate any help i recieve. Below is var transakcije being displayed in console.log().

---

[image]

---

```
function getBlockchainTransactions(blockNumber){
    var tx = [];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        for(var i=0; i<blockNumber; i++){
            web3.eth.getBlock(i, function(error, block){
            if(!error && block.transactions.length != 0){
                console.log(block.transactions);
                tx.push(block.transactions);
            }
        })
        }
            resolve(tx);
    });

}


async function msg() {
    const transakcije = await getBlockchainTransactions(blockNumber);
    console.log(transakcije);
}
```

Comment: transakcije[0][0] should work

Comment: `transakcije[0][0]` is correct, though the little "i" next to the log suggests me that it was immediately evaluated, hence I'm guessing that it may be the result of an asynchronous operation... is it?

Comment: Yes, this is asynchronous operation. I've tried again with transakcije[0][0] and i get error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Show more code context. There isn't enough detail in question as to where in that asynchronous code you try to access the array. What you see in console is likely being populated after you are logging it

Comment: `web3.eth.getBlock` is async, hence you are calling `resolve` **before** actually adding the elements to the array. You should make an async for, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBlock` is async, hence you are resolving an empty array because `for` loops in javascript are synchronous, but you're using an async callback inside them, and `resolve` is called **before** `tx.push` is.

I would suggest you a recursive async approach, like this:

```
function getBlockchainTransactions(blockNumber){
    var tx = [];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
            // declare a recrusive async loop.
         var recursiveAsyncLoop = function(current, max) {
            // If the current index is exactly blockNumber, resolve.
          if (current === max) {
            resolve(tx);
          }
          // Otherwise, excute the operation on the actual block.
          else {
            var i = current;
            web3.eth.getBlock(i, function(error, block){
              if(!error && block.transactions.length != 0){
                console.log(block.transactions);
                tx.push(block.transactions);
                // once the operation is finished, increase the counter on the next call.
                recursiveAsyncLoop(current + 1, max);
              }
              // In cany case, regardless the above is true or false, continue.
              else recursiveAsyncLoop(current + 1, max);
            })
          }
         }
         // Begin the loop, from index 0 until blockNumber (excluded).
         recursiveAsyncLoop(0, blockNumber);
    });

}


async function msg() {
    const transakcije = await getBlockchainTransactions(blockNumber);
    console.log(transakcije);
}
```

The above code should call `resolve` only when the items are effectively added to the array.

Comment: It works now, it can be accessed with double arrays like transakcije[216][0].

Comment: @energetics you may customize it by removing useless code. For instance, you may refactor by calling recursiveAsyncLoop in the `else` only once, just take the above as an example, it **can** be improved ;)